# Google search alike SearchView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, searchview, android-styles

I've would like set to grey color(icons and text) but now is showing as white color.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="end">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Titulo_ventana"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation">

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/mySearchview"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
            </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

I'd would like to reach something like this searchview within the toolbar and gray textcolor:

The left and right menu icons are optional.
The searchview is foldable by default, I don't mind if this feature should be changed.

[image]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your version as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search view, that you want to achieve in fact is not a `SearchView`. It's a custom component. Here's the view tree that can be obtained using [Hierarchy Viewer](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer) tool:

[image]

Here's the `OverlaySearchPlateContainer`:

[image]

As you can see from package name, it is shipped with Play Services, thus source code is not available.

Nevertheless, we can compare that tree with the tree of `SearchView`. Here's tree that can be obtained when ordinary `SearchView` is used:

[image]

Thus, you can see, that `OverlaySearchPlateContainer` is **not** a descendant of a `SearchView`, hence the UI you want to achieve cannot be accomplished using solely styles/themes.

I would recommend to not reinvent a wheel and to utilize 3rd party libraries, for example [*SearchBar-SearchView*](https://github.com/lapism/SearchBar-SearchView), where `SearchView` widget looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Even if this answer does not fit my requirements, is for sure the best answer in terms of learning.

Answer (score 1):

I have one solution its working fine in my application. You may try this.

```
EditText txtSearch = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
txtSearch.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search));
txtSearch.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
txtSearch.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the text color, put this in your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MySearchView" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hint_color</item>
</style>
```

Replace `@color/text_color` and `@color/hint_color` to suit your needs.

And then change the `SearchView` theme attribute in your XML layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/mySearchview"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/MySearchView">
</android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
```

Comment: @Ricardo Is the text color not changed (after you type some text)? I edited my answer to account for the "hint" text as well.

Comment: Is like style is being ignored. Finally i try @MayourPatel answer and I got it work!

Answer (score 0):

> You can set the background of search view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchViewContact"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:searchIcon="@mipmap/icon_search"
            app:closeIcon="@mipmap/icon_close"
            android:background="@drawable/search_view_background"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
```

> search_view_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#dcdee1"/>
    <stroke
        android:color="#d7d3d3"
        android:width="1dp"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```